# Using the first row of a CSV as the keys in nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, tuples

Please don't be brutal! I'm new to coding and have looked all over the web to find answers. I have a CSV with column one listing names, column 2 listing jobs, and column 3 listing birth months. I want the output I typed below the code. I have the dictionary made, but it is in this format: {"Karen Fisher": ("IT","November"), etc.} I want the keys of the nested dictionaries to be from the header of the csv so that people know what kind of data they are looking at about each person. I'm getting this error: "TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment"

```
with open("Example1.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    row1  = next(csvreader)
    #print(row1)

    def makeadictionary(csvreader):
        dct = {}
        keys = []
        valuesdict = {}
        names = []
        next(csvreader)
        for row in csvreader:
            keys.append(row[0])
            dct[row[0]] = row[1],row[2]
            names.append(row[0])
        #print(names)
        for key,value in dct.items():
            value = list(value)
            #print(value)
            job = value[0]
            #print(job)
            birthmonth = value[1]  
            #print(birthmonth)
            dct[key][row1[1]] = job
            dct[key][row1[2]] = birthmonth
        return dct
    print(makeadictionary(csvreader))
```

Goal output: {"Karen Fisher":{"job": "IT", "birth month": "November"}, etc.}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following line in your code:

```
dct[row[0]] = row[1],row[2]
```

This creates a a dictionary of the following form:

```
{"Karen Fisher": ("IT", "November")}
```

Note that "Karen Fisher" maps to a tuple of size 2, that is, if you access `dct["Karen Fisher"]` you get the tuple `("IT", "November")`. Now look at the line causing the error:

```
dct[key][row1[1]] = job
```

We know that `dct[key]` is equal to `("IT", "November")` and that `row1[1]` is equal to `"job"`, so what python is trying to execute is the following expression:

```
("IT", "November")["job"] = job
```

So the structure of this is `a[b] = c` where `a` is a tuple. This doesn't work for a couple of reasons, one of them that you can't do an indexed assignment of that form for a tuple (tuples can only be created, but not modified), the other is that you can't index a tuple with a string.

What you seem to want to do is to assign an item in a dictionary, but you don't have a dictionary in hand: `dct` is a dictionary, but `dct[key]` is a tuple. What you can do is instead *create* a dictionary:

```
dct[key] = {row1[1]: job, row1[2]: birthmonth]}
```

This should work, but there's another little issue. It's generally not good practice to modify a dictionary while you're iterating through it. You also don't need to iterate through everything twice. And I think you have a bug where you skip your first line of data after the header (in the `next(csvreader)` call in `makeadictionary`). Finally, you don't need to create a nested function for what you want to accomplish.

What I would recommend is the following:

```
 with open("Example1.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    header_row  = next(csvreader)
    result = {}
    for row in csvreader:
      name = row[0]
      result[name] = {}
      for field_name, value in zip(header_row[1:], row[1:]):
        # The zip function 'mixes' the two lists:
        # zip([a, b, c], [d, e, f]) == [(a, d), (b, e), (c, f)]
        result[name][field_name] = value
  print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The csv.DictReader class will return you a dictionary.  All you have to do is store the entries by key:

```
from pprint import pprint
import csv

f = open('x.csv','r')

track = {}
for row in csv.DictReader(f):
    track[row['name']] = dict(row)

pprint( track )
```

Output:

```
{'Joe Blow': {'birth month': 'April', 'job': 'HR', 'name': 'Joe Blow'},
 'Karen Fisher': {'birth month': 'November',
                  'job': 'IT',
                  'name': 'Karen Fisher'}}
```